# routerLink no funciona en componentes ionic4

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

soy nuevo en ionic.. y necesito navegar entre pantallas pero no me funciona el routerLink. 
La estructura de mi proyecto se compone de paginas y componentes... en mi componente realizo la logica que necesito y luego lo llamo en mi pagina
`

```
<ion-item lines="none">
        <ion-avatar slot="start">
            <img src="http://192.168.0.119:8000/imagenes/perfil/{{empresa.emp_foto}}">
        </ion-avatar>
        <ion-label>
            <h3>{{empresa.emp_nom}}</h3>
            <p>{{empresa.emp_info}}</p>
        </ion-label>
    </ion-item>
    <a routerLink="/empresa">Ver</a>
`
```

Esto es dentro de un componente llamado empresa... lo que quiero que haga es que me redireccione a una pagina tambien llamada empresa, pero no realiza ninguna accion..
Pero si entro a mi pagina tab1 y llamo mi componente `<app-empresas [empresas]="empresas"></app-empresas>` y luego le agrego el routerLink `<app-empresas [empresas]="empresas" routerLink="/empresa"></app-empresas>`
funciona sin problemas... Necesito que funcione en mi componente ya quiero enviar unos parametros al servidor

Comment: Hola Hernan, como tienes definida la ruta de tu componente `empresa` en el `routing.module`?

Comment: Hola.. no esta definida ahi ya que es un componente y no una pagina

Comment: Debe agregar RouterModule a los imports todos los @NgModule() donde vayas a usar rutas en este caso la de tus componentes donde los componentes usan routerLink o <router-outlet>.